# Flock webhook token

Tags: slack, flock

I am trying to create webhook as per this document and this doesn't include any clue about where does the token comes from.
https://docs.flock.com/display/flockos/Create+An+Incoming+Webhook

My curl command as below

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"   https://api.flock.com/hooks/sendMessage/guid-guid  -d '{"text": "This is a test message.","token":"test"}'
```

Error message:

```
{"error":"InvalidParameter","description":"A required parameter for the method call is missing or invalid","parameter":"token"}
```

Can someone point me what's missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Flock gives you the token for the webhook when you finish adding a new one at https://dev.flock.com/webhooks

You can look it up again when you're done by going to the edit option for the webhook you've added; at the moment the token is given at the bottom of the page:

Webhook URL

Send your JSON payload to this URL

[your-token-here]

Comment: If you could add an example to support your answer, would be helpful.